# .toggle() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to apply the toggle function to the two buttons separately. However, when I use the code below, it toggles both content under each button. How can I separate them so that when I click the first button only the content under it will be toggled?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Toggle</button>
<p>Hello</p>
<p style="display: none">Good Bye</p>

<button>Toggle</button>
<p>Hello</p>
<p style="display: none">Good Bye</p>

<script>
$("button").click(function () {
$("p").toggle();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple:** use `nextUntil()`.
Will select all the next elements until matched element reached (in your case the next `button`):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsbin.com/eroyas/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$("button").click(function () {
     $(this).nextUntil('button').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Works! What is the .nextUntil thing?

Comment: @wcdomy as I said, it will collect all the elements he founds (in our case the `<p>` elements) until selector reached (`'button'`). http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil **but not including** the selector we mention (the next `<button>`), ideal to use in your case!

Comment: If I want to change the text for the button once it's clicked. For example, from "Edit" to "Save". How can I do that? @Roko C. Buljan

Comment: Sure you can: http://jsbin.com/eroyas/3/edit  Please, take in consideration to accept an answer! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @wcdomy You can also use ternary operators to check / change text: http://jsbin.com/eroyas/4/edit

Comment: I see. What if I want to add another button. So initially there's only one "Edit" button. After I click it, it's replaced by two buttons which are "Save" and "Cancel". What's the trick? @Roko C. Buljan

Comment: I really don't understand  your last Q. YOu could also create a new SO question with the new issue you have! Here are lot of people online every day!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $(this).nextAll("p:lt(2)").toggle();
});
```

http://jsbin.com/orujav

Comment: If I want to change the text for the button once it's clicked. For example, from "Edit" to "Save". How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Why have two paragraph tags for this? Make your HTML:

```
<button>Toggle</button>
<p>Hello</p>

<button>Toggle</button>
<p>Hello</p>
```

and your jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).next('p').html( ($(this).next('p').html()=='Hello')?'Good Bye':'Hello');
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jHSfH/)**